# How to return a serialized List or Ilist in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, list, ilist

I'm developing a WCF web service using visual studio, and I'm using LINQ to query from the database.
The problem is, when the function return a List of Ilist, the browser show me an error

> The web page is not available

.
This is my code in the interface:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    IList<Person_type> GetPeopleTypes();
```

And this is the implementation code of the function:

```
public IList<Person_type> GetPeopleTypes()
    {

        IList<Person_type> result=new List<Person_type> (); 
        IList<Person_type> pts = db.Person_type.ToList();
        foreach (Person_type pt in pts)
            result.Add(pt) ;   

        return result;
    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: This error message has nothing to do with `LINQ`.

Comment: so, what should i do to return a list of people types?

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to return interface types from WCF-services (beacause of serialization problems https://stackoverflow.com/a/6732883/4585429).

Try to rewrite your method like this:

```
public List<Person_type> GetPeopleTypes()
{
    return db.Person_type.ToList();
}
```

or like this:

```
public Person_type[] GetPeopleTypes()
{
    return db.Person_type.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Ensure that you really open service host that has WebHttpBinding endpoint.

Comment: yes, it is already webHttpBinding. And there are many functions work correctly with me, but they return string.

Comment: Ok, strings are working. May be this one will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781739/4585429